# Android Releasing to Google Play Multiple Packages

Tags: android, package

I am about to release my app to Google Play. My project has multiple packages for organizational purposes. Will this cause a problem? Should I move all my .java files into one package?

Comment: No, it will not cause an issue. I recommend NOT moving all your classes to one package :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have as many packages as you want in your project, the only one that matters to the android market is the one that you declare in the manifest file `package="com.mypackage.miproyect"` because that one will be marked as the application id, so it should be unique.